# ng-binding, $scope variable empty when called in html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

the variable comes empty when binded on html

HTML code:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="roomInfo">
...

<div id="modal" ng-controller="roomListCtrl" class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">{{ room[0].name }}
```

JS code:

```
 var roomInfo = angular.module('roomInfo', []);

roomInfo.controller('roomListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get("/room-list-info/").then(function(response) {
        $scope.rooms = response.data;
    });

    $scope.getRoom = function (id) {
        var url = "/room-info/"+ id +"/";
        console.log(id);
        $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
            $scope.room = response.data;
            console.log($scope.room[0].name + "hola");
        });
    };


});
```

The console.log() shows the info that i want but for some reason it doesnt go to the html
Also the rooms[0].name works just the room[0].name doesnt work

Comment: what is `response.data`? An array? Can you log what `response.data` is?

Comment: How is your getRoom called?

Comment: its called with ng-click
ng-click="getRoom( r.id )"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you call $scope.getRoom outside of Angular context. You either need to use Angular bindings like ng-click, or manually do $scope.$apply.

Comment: it was out of the controller scope

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning $scope.rooom[0] is undefined so angular crash when you want room[0].name. try this `{{ room[0] ? room[0].name: '' }}`

Comment: No, for Angular bindings it doesn't matter